# React Native UI for native application?

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, merge, native

I'm done coding some **core functionalities** of an Android app, these had to be implemented in standard **native Java code**. Broadly speaking, it launches a Service and reads from a local DB with a SQLiteOpenHelper, but this last component will be replaced in the future for Bluetooth communication.

Now, I'd like to implement the **UI using React Native**; what's my best bet to combine native code with a UI made with React Native?

I have seen some options out there, but if there's any React Native expert familiarised with this, his/her tips and guidance would be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a service which you call occasionally then you create a react-native app, define your helper as a native module and call it from react-native.

It takes some time (and frustration so be prepared) to get going but after the first native module it will be quite straight forward. [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) is a guide to implement a native (java) module in android.

Launching an activity is different story.